# Extracting single values and keys from an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

Right now, I have a structure like this:

```
[
  { asin: "B000O3GCFU", name: "Thermos...", price: "$10.19" },
  { asin: "B0025Y6742", name: "Thermos...", price: "$12.19" }
  # ...
]
```

So, an array of hashes.

How can I extract single keys and values of each of the hashes? Like:

```
[
  { asin: "B000O3GCFU" },
  { asin: "B0025Y6742" }
  # ...
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map and create new hashes containing only "asin" on the fly:

```
 a.map {|h| {:asin => h[:asin]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
product_hash[:product].map do |product|
  product.slice(:asin) # if you have activesupport
  product.select { |key, val| key == :asin } # if you don't
end
```

Comment: `product.select { |key, val| key == :asin }` works, but `{ :asin => product[:asin] }` is much more efficient.

Comment: Duplication, yuck :) Seriously though - the slice/select approach let's you select more keys easily if you want to